# how to distinguish barcode input from keyboard input

Tags: c#, barcode

I want to distinguish Keyboard input from barcode input in c# programming

without adding prefix or suffix to barcode.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a minute and read [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order for you to ask a better question, and for others to better understand you and give you answers you need.

Comment: Usually, if you want to do this, it's best to use the scanner in whatever alternative mode it has that is in contrast to "keyboard shim" mode. I.e. don't have the tool pretend to be a keyboard to then turn around and try to distinguish it from a keyboard. Whether your tool supports such an other mode would depend on the specific tool and should be found in the manual for it.

Comment: I second Damiens solution. I usually go with the USB OEM/OPOS mode + Microsofts POS library. Not sure if all barcode scanners support it but I'd guess it's pretty standard.

Comment: It would be great if you can tell us what's the actual problem. Try checking the typing speed?

Answer (score -1):

try to get the Key Pressed event from the textbox.

Comment: Well implemented keyboard shims for scanners appear *as* a second keyboard on the system. They'll create all of the events that real keys will. If the OP isn't experiencing the effects of a keyboard shim, it's unclear what the problem would be since the input experience is typically *completely* different if directly interfacing with the scanner.